# How to know that google adsense ad is loaded with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adsense

I need to know that my google adsense ad (in div id="bottomAd") is loaded.

I tried to wait 5 sec, parse div, and get all "a":

```
function OnBodyLoad() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var bottomAd = document.getElementById("bottomAd");
        var linkArray = bottomAd.getElementsByTagName("a");//it's always empty
    }, 5000);
}
```

It's now working.

Adsense load with iframe that has their own body. So that how to get all "a" element? Or other way to know that adsense ad is loaded?

I can't load iframe content because of private policy (prevented XSS attack). So next code doesn't wokrs:

```
var array = new Array();
findIframeLinks(bottomAd, "a", array);
```

...

```
function findIframeLinks(element, returnElementTagName, array) {
    array.push(element.getElementsByTagName(returnElementTagName));
    var innerIframes = element.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for (var i = 0; i < innerIframes.length; i++) {
        if (innerIframes[i].contentDocument) {
            var body = innerIframes[i].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            findIframeLinks(body, returnElementTagName, array);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have never used google adsense before but I suspect there will be some events you can subscribe to tell whether something has occur or not.

I did some research on your behalf and found this documentation to be particularly useful, I think the event you are looking for is the ADS_LOADED event. Just do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> find on the link for 'ADS_LOADED'
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1705827?hl=en

Here is the sample code suggested by the doc.

```
adsLoader.addEventListener(AdsLoadedEvent.ADS_LOADED, onAdsLoaded);
```

Comment: Samuel, thanks for reply. I'm not professional Javascript developer, but are you sure it's works in Javascript? Syntax is unfamiliar for me. And documentation (named "AdSense for video") tells "SDK allows you to request AdSense ads through Flash’s ActionScript language ".